# Python group by two columns and filter to get specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Data like this:

[image]

I **grouped the data by** ('**Month**' and '**type_failure**') to get the number of falls associated with each type_failure:

```
cols = ["Month", "Type_failure"]
grouped_df1 = df.groupby(cols).size()
```

[image]

I want to filter the grouped data to get the the **'Roof fall' cases only**. **The expected output should be:**

[image]

This is what I have done, but it did not work.

```
filtered_group = grouped_df1.filter(lambda x: x[x['Type_failure'] == 'Roof fall'])
print(filtered_group)
```

Any idea how to solve this problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cols = ["Month", "Type_failure"]
grouped_df1 = df.groupby(cols).size()
grouped_df1.unstack()[['Roof fall']].stack()
# to get as a new dataframe, use below code
# df2 = pd.DataFrame(grouped_df1.unstack()[['Roof fall']].stack()).rename(columns={0: "count"})
```

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense for you to filter before grouping:

```
df.loc[df['Type_failure'] == 'Roof fall'].groupby(cols).size()
```